# How to use onChange in react-select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to create onChange function in my react-select. Here is my following code:

```
  const find = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.target.value === "Users") {
      setSearchUsers(true);
      setSearchTeams(false);
    } else if (event.target.value === "Teams") {
      setSearchUsers(false);
      setSearchTeams(true);
    }
  };

  <Select
    className="search-select"
    instanceId="long-value-select"
    closeMenuOnSelect={false}
    components={animatedComponents}
    defaultValue="Select"
    isMulti
    onChange={(e) => find(e.target.value)}
    options={searchData}
  />
```

When I try to change options it's giving me this error

> TypeError: event.preventDefault is not a function

How can I use onChange function in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are passing the `event.target.value` into the `find` method and then using that event value to get the  `event.target.value` again. You do not need to do this again as you already passed the value. The `prevenDefault()` method does not exist on the event's value but it exists on the event object itself. Just pass the event object as the argument to use the `preventDefault()`.

```
 onChange={(e) => find(e)}
```

Comment: onChange={find} will automatically pass the event to function.

Answer (score 2):

Just update `onChange` like this:

```
onChange={(e) => find(e)}
```

or shorter:

```
onChange={find}
```

Comment: still getting the error `TypeError: event.preventDefault is not a function`

Comment: What are you using `preventDefault` for? Is it to stop a form from submitting?

Comment: `onChange` in react-select return a value not an event so you cannot use `event.preventDefault`

Comment: I see. Thanks for pointed out the mistake for me. So how do I change my onChange function to make it work with react-select? When I selected an option and I `console.log(value)` it's giving me this `0: label: "Users", value: "Users"`

Answer (score 1):

This handler only passes the *value* of the event to `find`, not the *event*, and the value doesn't have a `preventDefault` method.

```
onChange={(e) => find(e.target.value)}
```

Pass the event to the function just using the handler...

```
onChange={find}
```

...and then have the function extract the value

```
function find(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const { value } = e.target;
  if (value === 'Users') {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> onChange={(e) => find(e.target.value)}

You're passing the selected value to the find function which is a **value** not an event therefore you get the error.

Changing it to `onChange={find}` will work smoothly because the default action  is cancellable.