How to filter data from select using React and TypeScript
I'm trying to filter the data by select, but I don't know why my code doesn't work. In the console I can see that it correctly shows me the selected items (option). I noticed that the problem is onChange, which shows undefined in the console even though the value is correctly shown.
 <FormLabel htmlFor="type">Type</FormLabel>
            <Select
              value={selectedType}
              onChange={(e) => setSelectedType(e.target.value)}
              id="type"
            >
              <option value="mtb">MTB bike</option>
              <option value="country">Country</option>
            </Select>
          </FormControl>

<Box className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-6">
        {currentProducts.map((data) => (
          <Card key={data.id} maxW="sm">
          // rest code

  const currentProducts = selectedType ? products.filter((item) => item.type === selectedType) : products.slice(startIndex, startIndex + productsPerPage)

 const [selectedType, setSelectedType] = useState("");

export const products: Products[] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    price: 1800,
    type: "country",
  },

export interface Products {
id: number;
price: number;
type: string;
}


Hi, To debug, please see what if this statement  const currentProducts = selectedType ? products.filter((item) => item.type === selectedType) : products.slice(startIndex, startIndex + productsPerPage) changed to  const currentProducts = products , this test may help to spot the point of failure.

@WeDoTheBest4You I noticed that the problem is onChange, which shows undefined in the console even though the value is correctly shown

Will this improve the code : onChange={setSelectedType}

There are some answers here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68790381/how-to-use-onchange-in-react-select

None of the advice works

Apparently there is nothing incorrect in the code you have shared. When I tried to replicate the issue with the code below, it did not fail, and it worked well. I request you may please go through this code use it to match it with yours, perhaps it may help you to spot the cause of failure. Or if you can share your original code via Github, I shall take a detailed look.
App.js
import { useState } from 'react';
import FormLabel from '@mui/material/FormLabel';
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';

export default function App() {
  const [selectedType, setSelectedType] = useState('');
  const currentProducts = selectedType
    ? products.filter((item) => item.type === selectedType)
    : products;

  return (
    <FormControl>
      <FormLabel htmlFor="type">Type</FormLabel>
      <select
        value={selectedType}
        onChange={(e) => setSelectedType(e.target.value)}
        id="type"
      >
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="mtb">MTB bike</option>
        <option value="country">Country</option>
      </select>
      <FormLabel component="legend">
        Product list filtered on type : {selectedType}
      </FormLabel>
      <ol>
        {currentProducts.map((p) => (
          <li key={p.id}>Product Id {p.id}</li>
        ))}
      </ol>
    </FormControl>
  );
}

const products = [
  {
    id: 1,
    type: 'country',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    type: 'mtb',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    price: 1800,
    type: 'country',
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    price: 1800,
    type: 'mtb',
  },
];

npm list
react.dev@0.0.0
├── @emotion/react@11.13.3
├── @emotion/styled@11.13.0
├── @mui/icons-material@6.0.2
├── @mui/material@6.0.2
├── react-dom@18.3.1
├── react-scripts@5.0.1
└── react@18.3.1

Test run:

On load:



On selection of type




Hi, Thank you for the vote. What did really go wrong in this case ?

thanks for your help, this code actually in the test ide works so I am sure that at least with the code is all right, I have to figure out why it does not want to work at my environment. I can't say what is going wrong at this moment, it is a strange case

Ok, Thank you. Carry on, shall be in touch.

I found the cause. It turns out that the code works when those elements it wants to display are in the same component as the filters. Previously, they were separate: a separate component with filters and a separate one with cards

Ok, you would be right. One doubt with me is that currentProducts.map((data) is the driver, whatever data it gives to Card, it just shows, Card does not have a separate state. In that case, it should not be a problem. I might be missing some points, please correct me if so.

There is probably a way to transfer this data. In the Card component there is basically the Card itself, which takes the currentProducts data from the custom Hook, which also contains this useStae, the filtering component also uses the data from the custom Hook in the same way. Maybe I need to read more about the relationship between the components, but since both components take data from custom Hook there should be no problem?

It seems currentProducts has the data - more specifically the filtered data, then Card is to display it. If so, Card needs to get data via props. Still you know the context better than me, please take the best route.

It is just as you say. Thank you for your help!

You have to use useEffect / Upon choosing from select, call a function update the selectedType state and the currentProducts.

None of the advice works.
